# Do you write unit testing or TDD as a line item requirement into your contracts or statements of work?

Tags: unit-testing, tdd, continuous-integration

If you do, do you discuss coverage, continuous integration, quality control, or anything related to the difference between unit testing, functional testing and TDD in general? If clients ask, do you simply state that you will unit test, but leave out specifics?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMO,unit testing is akin to an implementation detail. They are hidden, yet quite an unwritten expectation.

TDD would fall into this category as well since, again, it is really a process of software development. The contract defines expectations, not a process.

If a summary of time is expected, these should generally fall into categories of Design and Testing.

Comment: Yes, but unit tests are a derivation of acceptance tests and requirements.  I think part of the reason that unit testing may be a line item is to make it a first-class citizen, and not just part of the "busy work" of completing the requirements.

Comment: @Robert: fair enough ... *yes we unit test and yes, that is where part of your money goes*. I have simply taken unit testing as a given.

Answer (score 1):

Not as such, but we have a specified level of decision coverage and function coverage as the final acceptance criteria for our software, so we use unit tests to achieve this.

So we've made writing unit tests to achieve this level of coverage part of our definition of done. We're not doing TDD.